# How to get which version of cron daemon is running

Tags: cron

Background: I am working on CentOS

**Details**

```
# cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.18-308.4.1.el5PAE (mockbuild@builder10.centos.org) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)) #1 SMP Tue Apr 17 17:47:38 EDT 2012
```

Question: How can i know which **version cron daemon** installed and running on machine

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The dummy way:

```
whereis -b crontab | cut -d' ' -f2 | xargs rpm -qf
```

Comment: Nice Answer. Would you please explain the command?

Comment: search for a binary named crond, get the 2nd column of the output(the binary), then pass to rpm to look for it's belonging package. Note that in RHEL/CentOS cron daemon is named crond but not in some other OS. So I edited and use "crontab" instead which is more general. You can even filter from ps to figure out what binary is running

Comment: +1 for your helpful Answer. Also thanks for your helpful comment.

Answer (score 3):

On your centos system: `rpm -q vixie-cron`

Should be something like vixie-cron-4.1-77.el5_4.1

Answer (score 3):

In EL6, you can check the version of cronie (contains crond) with yum:

```
sudo yum list installed cronie
```

fyi, cronie replaced vixie-cron in EL6.