# Use service_facts module to show the current version of the cron process?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, ansible, module

I am learning Ansible from this book and it contains this lab:

> Write a playbook according to the following specifications:
>
> - The cron module must be used to restart your managed servers at 2 a.m. each weekday
> - After rebooting a message must be written to syslog with the text "CRON initiated reboot completed"
> - The default systemd target must be set to multi-target
> - The last task should use service facts to show the current version of the cron process

The last point is a bit confusing. The service_facts module only retrieves facts relating to the name,source,state and status of crond but not the version. How can this objective be achieved?

Comment: What book is it?

Comment: Please note that, out of the context of a pure learning exercise, rebooting a server every weekday at 2 a.m. using cron looks like a very bad idea.

Comment: Red Hat RHCE 8 (EX294) Cert Guide - Sander van Vugt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a mistake. The request looks suspicious (or ambiguous at least): `'use service facts to show the current version of the cron process'`. There is no version among the attributes of the [service facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/service_facts_module.html#ansible-builtin-service-facts-return-service-state-information-as-fact-data), e.g. (running on Ubuntu)

```yaml
    - service_facts:
    - debug:
        var: ansible_facts.services['cron.service']
```

gives

```yaml
  ansible_facts.services['cron.service']:
    name: cron.service
    source: systemd
    state: running
    status: enabled
```

Moreover, `'version of process'` looks weird. Perhaps they want `'PID of process'`? In this case, use *systemd*, e.g.

```yaml
    - systemd:
        name: "{{ ansible_facts.services['cron.service']['name'] }}"
      register: result
    - debug:
        var: result.status.ExecMainPID
```

gives

```yaml
  result.status.ExecMainPID: '884'
```

<sup>(See also: `shell> systemctl status cron.service`)</sup>

The next option might be that they want `'version of cron binary'`. In this case, use [*package_facts*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/package_facts_module.html#ansible-builtin-package-facts-package-information-as-facts), e.g.

```yaml
    - package_facts:
    - debug:
        var: ansible_facts.packages.cron.0.version
```

gives

```yaml
  ansible_facts.packages.cron.0.version: 3.0pl1-136ubuntu1
```

See more sophisticated options in [How to get which version of cron daemon is running](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55676/how-to-get-which-version-of-cron-daemon-is-running). They might be automated in Ansible as well.

Comment: thanks, and yes I think its a mistake. The chapter for this exercise covers the systemd module so I presume it's that